# Filter out Non null and undefined items based on a property from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

How can i filter items from an array of objects with conditional check on a property of type string

My JSON is like this

```
{"startIndex":2,"selections":[{"type":"SKU","colIndex":0,"values":[{"value":1231319,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":2,"selected":false},{"value":1231320,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":3,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":4,"selected":false},{"value":1231322,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":5,"selected":false},{"value":1231323,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":6,"selected":false},{"value":1231324,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":7,"selected":false},{"value":1231325,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":8,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":9,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":10,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":11,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":12,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":13,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":14,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":15,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":16,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":17,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":18,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":19,"selected":false}]},{"type":"QTY","colIndex":1,"values":[{"value":2,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":2,"selected":false},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":3,"selected":false},{"value":-1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":4,"selected":false},{"value":0,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":5,"selected":false},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":6,"selected":false},{"value":2,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":7,"selected":false},{"value":3,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":8,"selected":false},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":9,"selected":false},{"value":"Some more products under a merged cell just to be annoying","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":10,"selected":false},{"value":"product ID","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":11,"selected":false},{"value":333444,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":12,"selected":false},{"value":333445,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":13,"selected":false},{"value":333446,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":14,"selected":false},{"value":333447,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":15,"selected":false},{"value":333448,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":16,"selected":false},{"value":333449,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":17,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":18,"selected":false},{"value":333451,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":1,"rowIndex":19,"selected":false}]},{"type":"Name","colIndex":2,"values":[{"value":"BRONZE HAT","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":2,"selected":true},{"value":"GOLD HAT","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":3,"selected":true},{"value":"unknown?","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":4,"selected":true},{"value":8,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":5,"selected":true},{"value":"this data is a bit messy%","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":6,"selected":true},{"value":"Trouser A","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":7,"selected":true},{"value":"Trouser B","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":8,"selected":true},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":9,"selected":true},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":10,"selected":true},{"value":"quantity required","bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":11,"selected":true},{"value":2,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":12,"selected":true},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":13,"selected":true},{"value":-1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":14,"selected":true},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":15,"selected":true},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":16,"selected":true},{"value":2,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":17,"selected":true},{"value":3,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":18,"selected":true},{"value":1,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":2,"rowIndex":19,"selected":true}]}]}
```

I am using the following typescript  but still all items are returned

```
 var selected_skus = this.selectionSettings.selections.filter(e => e.type === 'SKU' && e.values.filter(x=>x.value?.length >0 ))
      .map(obj => obj.values);
    console.log(selected_skus);
```

How can i ensure that items with a not null  x.value  is returning back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using filters inside of filters in this way. You're looking to filter by SKU, and then *for each matching set of skus* map the values array over. Additionally the `.length` property exists on strings, so we cast it as a string to check.

```
json.selections.filter(e => e.type === 'SKU') // first get an array of all SKU sets
    .map(s => ({...s,  values:s.values // map each set of SKUs, transforming the values array within
                 .filter(x=>x.value?.toString().length >0 )})) // filter that property exists && is is not empty
```

```js
let json = {"startIndex":2,"selections":[{"type":"SKU","colIndex":0,"values":[{"value":1231319,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":2,"selected":false},{"value":1231320,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":3,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":4,"selected":false},{"value":1231322,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":5,"selected":false},{"value":1231323,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":6,"selected":false},{"value":1231324,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":7,"selected":false},{"value":1231325,"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":1,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":8,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":9,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":10,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":11,"selected":false},{"bgcolour":"","textcolour":"","type":0,"colIndex":0,"rowIndex":19,"selected":false}]}]}
let selected_skus = json.selections.filter(e => e.type === 'SKU').map(s => ({...s, values:s.values.filter(x=> x.value?.toString().length >0 )}))
console.log(selected_skus)
```

Comment: Answer form Rahul is also working Not sure which will perform better in all use cases and more complex scenarios.

Comment: @Sebastian - we have basically the same answer except mine was 12 minutes before Rahul's. Mine is more concise in the Map, Rahuls is more concise with the `!!value`. Rahuls will fail if the `value` is `0`, whereas this one won't - which matches the original pattern you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.values.filter(x=>x.value?.length > 0)
```

will always return an array. it might be an empty array [] - but it will still be an array. and arrays are "truthy" - so the second part oft

```
e => e.type === 'SKU' && e.values.filter(x=>x.value?.length > 0)
```

will evaluate to true either way. empty array or not.

what you will have to do instead is to check if the length of the filtered array is > 0, so

```
(e => e.type === 'SKU') && (e.values.filter(x=>x.value?.length > 0).length > 0)
```

but also your inner check of

```
x.value?.length > 0
```

doesn't really make sense since you are checking numbers there. checking on a length property of type number is not what you want. so in the end you will need

```
(e => e.type === 'SKU') && (e.values.filter(x => x !== null && x !== undefined).length > 0)
```

Comment: var selected_skus = this.selectionSettings.selections.filter(e => e.type === 'SKU' && (e.values.filter(x => x.value !== null && x.value !== undefined).length > 0) )
      .map(obj => obj.values); 
This is still returning all records back under SKU

Answer (score 1):

First filter by `type "SKU"` then map the filtered data and for each item filter the `data.values` property, and `assign the filtered values` to data.values property.

```js
let selectionSettings = {
  "startIndex": 2, "selections": [
    {
      "type": "SKU", "colIndex": 0, "values":
        [{ "value": 1231319, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 2, "selected": false },
        { "value": 1231320, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 3, "selected": false },
        { "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 0, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 4, "selected": false },
        { "value": 1231322, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 5, "selected": false },
        { "value": 1231323, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 6, "selected": false },
        { "value": 1231324, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 0, "rowIndex": 7, "selected": false }]
    },
    {
      "type": "QTY", "colIndex": 1, "values":
        [{ "value": 2, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 1, "rowIndex": 2, "selected": false },
        { "value": 1, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 1, "rowIndex": 3, "selected": false },
        { "value": -1, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 1, "colIndex": 1, "rowIndex": 4, "selected": false },
        { "value": 0, "bgcolour": "", "textcolour": "", "type": 0, "colIndex": 1, "rowIndex": 5, "selected": false }]
    }
  ]
};

const filterList = (list) => {
  return list.selections.filter(e => e.type === 'SKU')
    .map(data => {
      data.values = data.values.filter(({value}) => !(value === undefined || value === null));
      return data;
    });
}

console.log(filterList(selectionSettings));
```

Comment: Can we read the corresponding values from type:"QTY" and RowIndex  within the same filter? Final object is an array of  
[  {sku: value}{qty:value} ,  {sku: value}{qty:value}  ,  .... {sku: value}{qty:value}  ]

Comment: @Sebastian you want to filter for both `SKU and QTY`,  then yes you can do by adding AND condition `e.type === 'QTY'`